# Why is my Springboot main method launching 2 threads while it is invoked only once in code?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to regularly update a properties file. I first used a `Timer` that `scheduleAtFixedRate` a `TimerTask`. As it did not work as expected (there were always more than one timer running at a time), I decided to use a simple while loop in a thread, which loop sleeps most of the time.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties(StorageProperties.class)
public class ServerApplication {

    Package mainPackage = ServerApplication.class.getPackage();
    /**
     * This will return a version only if the entry "Implementation-Version"
     * exists in the Manifest file.
     */
    String version = mainPackage.getImplementationVersion();
    System.out.println(
            version);
    
    new Thread(() -> {

        try {
            while (true) {                 
                
              System.out.println(
                         Thread.currentThread().getName() + " is checking ");
                         
              // Code to write in properties 
              
              // Sleeps some time           
              Thread.sleep(GeneralSettings.CHECK_PERIOD_IN_S * 1000);
              
              // Code to read from properties file to check for updates
            
            } // end of while
            
         } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            // ...
         }
      }).start();
            
SpringApplication.run(ServerApplication.class,
            args);
```

}

What I see in the logs is :

> Thread-0 is checking
> Thread-4 is checking

Please note : while asking this question I also noticed that the version is also shown twice and has always been (I thought it was a logging configuration problem).

Why are 2 "Checking" threads launched whereas the `SpringApplication` is lauched only once as expected ?

What can I do to only have a single "Checking" thread instead of 2 ?

Any help appreciated :-)

Comment: Wild guess, are you using Spring Boot Devtools as a dependency?

Comment: @M.Deinum That's correct ! Would you mind elaborating ?

Comment: It will load/start classes twice, remove devtools and you will have a single one.

Comment: By removing devtools the line is shown only once, but other features do not work on dev machine (eg "njection of autowired dependencies failed"). So I will write a comment in code to warn this can happen! Anyway thank you @M.Deinum!

Comment: Autowiring shouldn't fail... Devtools will only allow restarts when changing code it doesn't contain dependency injection (unless you have no other dependencies?).

Comment: Right there were other dependencies that did not recompile and lead to autowiring failure because it did not rebuild the dependencies. I did it and actually Springboot launched flawlessly. Thanks for pointing this out.